ROS 2 Humble GPU Memory Leak on Jetson Orin NX
I'm running ROS 2 Humble on a Jetson Orin NX (16GB) and have been running multiple tests and ran into a GPU resource management pattern. When running nodes that utilize GPU resources for computation (using CUDA through PyCUDA), I'm seeing consistent memory leaks even with seemingly simple operations.
Environment:

NVIDIA Jetson Orin NX (16GB)
Ubuntu 22.04
ROS 2 Humble
CUDA 12.6.68
Jetpack 6.1

Observed Behavior:

GPU memory usage increases linearly over time
Number of stored CUDA arrays grows unbounded
No automatic resource cleanup
After ~5 minutes: ~15GB GPU memory consumed
GPU temperature remains stable around 49-50°C

Minimal reproduction:

Create a basic ROS 2 node that allocates GPU memory:

import pycuda.gpuarray as gpuarray
import numpy as np

class GPUNode(Node):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__('gpu_node')
        self._stored = []  # Leak: storing references without cleanup
        self.timer = self.create_timer(1.0, self.timer_callback)

    def timer_callback(self):
        # Allocate without cleanup
        array = gpuarray.to_gpu(np.random.rand(1000, 1000))
        self._stored.append(array)  # Leak: keeping reference


Is this a known issue with ROS 2's GPU resource handling on Jetson platforms? What are the recommended best practices for proper GPU resource management in ROS 2 nodes?

You posted nearly the same misinformed question in https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/113954  Are you trolling us?
